# MySQL fts index degrading performance until OPTIMIZE TABLE

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

It seems that when updating a mysql fulltext index, the query performance degrades over time -- perhaps about two months of updates, there a noticeable query degradation on a query such as:

```
WHERE  match(search) against ('Season1')
```

Is this a common experience? I've never heard of this before. Is it possible to 'rebuild' the fts index or something if it seems like the performance is degrading?

However, after running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` every month or so, it seems to fix the problem. What's going on here?

Comment: Alas, this seems to be common for InnoDB's `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: @RickJames -- thanks, any idea why from a technical perspective (i.e., where in the c++ source for ft)?