# Non-blocking optimize table

Tags: mysql, sql, nonblocking

I would like to use a non-blocking optimize table (I've tried doing the normal `OPTIMIZE` and I notice about ~2mins of downtime. Here is the code I currently have for this:

```py
@staticmethod
def optimize_table_nonblocking(tablename='eidrdedupe_test'):
    conn, cursor = get_new_db_conn_and_cursor()

    # populate a (potentially previously-existing) table with the data
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s_tmp' % tablename)
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE %s_tmp SELECT * FROM %s" % (tablename, tablename))

    # optimize that table
    cursor.execute("OPTIMIZE TABLE %s_tmp" % tablename)
    conn.commit()

    # swap the tables // keep the old table so we can examine it if we want
    cursor.execute('RENAME TABLE %s TO %s_tmp1' % (tablename, tablename))       # rename current table to _tmp1
    cursor.execute('RENAME TABLE %s_tmp TO %s' % (tablename, tablename))        # rename tmp table to main table
    cursor.execute('RENAME TABLE %s_tmp1 TO %s_tmp' % (tablename, tablename))   # now previous table is _tmp
    conn.commit()

    cursor.close(); conn.close()
```

Does this seem like a good approach, or are there things I'm missing / can improve?

[**Question**: How do I specify the code language in the markup?]

Comment: If the table has concurrent updates, those will be lost (you'd need to somehow re-apply them afterwards). If the table does not have concurrent updates, is the normal optimize directly on the table really a problem?

Comment: @Thilo -- yes, I'd prefer to re-run the updates (we store a log so that wouldn't be an issue) while this is running.

Comment: What storage engine are you using? The documentation claims that optimization is done online for InnoDB.

Comment: InnoDB -- it's to rebuild a fts index, which terribly degrades unless I run this whenever I make major updates to search-related stuff.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59796140/14955

Comment: I think I'd just live with the two minute downtime during scheduled maintenance. If that is not acceptable, investigate a more scalable/robust separate FTS system outside of the main database.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has flaws.

- It is doing essentially what `OPTIMIZE` does -- copy the table over and rebuild the indexes.
- You are optimizing twice -- once with the `CREATE .. SELECT`, then again with the `OPTIMIZE`.
- Any writes during the optimize will be lost.
- Do all the `RENAMEs` in a single `RENAME` statement to avoid the brief time when no table exists:  `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`

All of those say that your optimize script cannot be as good as the builtin one.

`pt-online-schema-change`, but doing no actual schema changes, is a free tool that does better.

Anyway, why are you using `OPTIMIZE`?  It is almost never of enough use to warrant doing it.  Is it just to rebuild an InnoDB `FULLTEXT` index?  Keep in mind that `OPTIMIZE` copies the table over and rebuilds all the indexes.

MySQL 8.0, I think, has an 'in-place' optimize.  Upgrade to get this.

Meanwhile, consider stopping reads and writes, `DROP INDEX` and `ADD INDEX` for the one `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: fantastic answer, thank you. Yes, this is for a `FULLTEXT` index -- two questions from your answer: (1) how would I do multiple renames in a single statement?; (2) what does optimize do to the ft index? Why can't the ft index 'keep optimized' itself?

Comment: @David542 - I updated with an RENAME example.  I assume the FT index is simply rebuilt.  I have yet to hear why it can't keep itself optimized.  (Non-FT indexes do a reasonable job of such.)